# Close To Cook Reduction given NP != coNP

Tags: reductions, complexity-classes, co-np, polynomial-time-reductions

I am struggling to answer these two questions:

Prove or wrong:
Both are given the assumption that NP != coNP.

1. For any 2 decision problems S, S', if there is a Cook reduction from S' to S then there exists a Cook reduction from S' complement to S complement.
2. The class NP intersection coNP is closed under Cook reduction.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  We discourage "here is an exercise-style task, please answer it for me" questions.

Comment: i am sory i was not aware of that , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption of $\text{P} \neq \text{NP}$ is not necessary here.

1. given a reduction $\Phi$ from a language $A$ to a language $B$, (that is polynomial time) then for every $x$ we have, $x\in A $ iff $\Phi(x) \in B$. Then (just as $p\rightarrow q$ is equivalent to $\neg q \rightarrow \neg p$) we have $x\notin A$ iff $\Phi(x)\notin B$.
2. As for why $\text{NP} \bigcap \text{co-NP}$ is closed under poly time reductions, it's just because you can emulate the machine calculating the reduction. I mean that if $\Phi$ is a reduction from $A$ to $B$ and $B\in \text{NP} \bigcap \text{co-NP}$, then to make a machine for $A$, start by calculating $\Phi(x)$ for input $x$ and use $B$'s machine on it afterwards.

Comment: You might consider not to encourage [undesirable posting behaviour](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/594).  Your choice!

Comment: You are right. Sorry for that!